# How can I authenticate a websocket connection where client and server reside on seperate domains?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, cookies, websocket, signalr

I'm currently playing around with SignalR and websockets. From my research, it seems, as websockets do not support custom headers, there's basically only two ways to authenticate a websocket connection during token based authentication.

1) Passing the token in the query string
2) Storing the token in a cookie which then gets passed to the server when WithCredentials is set to true

The first method isn't great practice - even through websocket communication is encrypted, query strings may be logged by servers etc.

The second method I have got working on my local machine but it doesn't work once deployed because my client and server reside on different domains. So basically, I have an Angular site that has one domain (eg. client.com) and a WebAPI site that alls CORS with a completely different domain (eg. server.com). On my browser, if I'm on client.com, I cannot set a cookie that gets sent to server.com on a request.

What is a good way to authenticate websockets when client and server sit on different domains?

Comment: I hate that it's so difficult to get authentication working with SignalR, it just seems like this is a basic requirement and I've been sitting for hours trying figure out how to get this going.

Answer (score 0):

The [WebSocket Protocol specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-10.5) doesn't specify any particular way for authentication. You need to perform the authentication during the handshake phase and for that you can use any HTTP authentication mechanism like Basic, Digest, etc.

Further you could look into [JWT token based authentication](https://jwt.io/introduction/). Angular app can store the token in [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and send it as a Transport header during the handshake request to the server. If the token is invalid, server can terminate the WebSocket connection upgrade request and the Angular app can re-direct the user to login page.

Comment: that's what I'm saying. I am using JWT token based authentications and I can't send it as a header because websockets don't support custom headers. I can't use cookies either as the server resides on a different domain

Comment: What is the websocket server implementation you are using?

Comment: SignalR - but this shouldn't matter. The problem is in the browser API which does not support custom headers

Comment: How about adding it as a query parameter? Request Filter at the server side can extract it and perform the authentication.

Comment: JavaScript client API doesn't provide a way to intercept the HTTP headers of the handshake response. Hence, for first time authentication you need to send the JWT token through the websocket connection

Comment: I can put it as a query parameter but that's not very secure as it could be stored in server logs.

Comment: In that case only available option is to perform the authentication once the websocket connection is established. You can send the JWT token as the first message to the server and if it is invalid, server can terminate the connection. But this comes with a overhead of completing the websocket handshake for each request.

Comment: yeah ok that's not actually a bad idea. So anyone can connect, but then the client needs to validate itself afterwards. And only clients who have validated itself can send or broadcast any messages.

Comment: Yes. Basically you need to implement your custom protocol on top of websocket

Comment: You can also try to whitelist your customers' IP addresses if possible to prevent the extra connections.  Or flipping it around, have multiple failed auth-by-message attempts blacklist the source IP.

Comment: Late to the party, but also researching the same problem. Unless you're planning to use heavy streams over the WS you could also communicate using STOMP. It's spec has authentication header which would fit your bill. It's like HTTP for websockets.

Comment: One possible way could be to use the Origin header and cookies. It's a combination of Security and Authentication. Using the Origin header, websocket server should only allow request from specific allowed domains and before making the websocket connection, make sure that JWT token is set in the cookies which can be used by the server to authenticate.